When to accept?
I  participated on two  Stack  sites extenively:

Drupal - you accepted as soon as your problem  was solved. Switching accept mark was normal.
Worldbuilding - it  is highly  discouraged to accept before 24 hours passed, to give people from all over  the globe fair chance  to answer and provide best idea without feeling neglected. Switching accepted answer is unusual.

What are customs about accepting on this stack?

I think it depends a little on the question type:
If you're asking for piece or set identification, and someone has found the answer for you, then accept as soon as you're happy - it saves people from clicking through to an ambiguous question.
If you're asking for building techniques however you may want to leave that open for a while as it's possible that you'll get a few different ways to approach your problem - feel free to vote and comment on answers as they come in, this also encourages participation as people can see you're actively involved in the answers.
